# Acomodar código en bucle

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que muestra los horóscopos, necesito que desaparezca uno cuando se muestre el otro, uno arriba y uno abajo y que desaparezca el de arriba cuando salga el de abajo, no se si me hago entender, con este código creo que me funciona como lo puedo acomodar?

```js
var horoscopo = null;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        horoscopo = this.response.horoscopo;
        //document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = this.response.horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.adderou.cl/tyaas/", true);
xhttp.send();

var horoscopo = null;


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        horoscopo = this.response.horoscopo;
        //document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = this.response.horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.adderou.cl/tyaas/", true);
xhttp.send();



var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video.ontimeupdate = function () {
    myFunction()
};


function myFunction() {

    var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
    var content2 = document.getElementById('content-text2');

    
    var contenido, contenedor;

    if (video.currentTime <= 9) {
        contenido = horoscopo.aries;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 16) {
        contenido = horoscopo.tauro;
        contenedor = content2;
        content.display = 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 24) {
        contenido = horoscopo.geminis;
        contenedor = content;
        content2.display = 'none';
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 33) {
        contenido = horoscopo.cancer;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 41) {
        contenido = horoscopo.leo;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 49) {
        contenido = horoscopo.virgo;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 57) {
        contenido = horoscopo.libra;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 65) {
        contenido = horoscopo.escorpion;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 73) {
        contenido = horoscopo.sagitario;
        contenedor = content;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 81) {
        contenido = horoscopo.capricornio;
        contenedor = content2;
    } else if (video.currentTime <= 89) {
        contenido = horoscopo.acuario;
        contenedor = content;
    } else {
        contenido = horoscopo.piscis;
        contenedor = content2;
    }

    content.display = contenedor==content ? 'block' : 'none';
    content2.display = contenedor==content2 ? 'block' : 'none';

    contenedor.innerText = contenido.nombre + ' : ' + contenido.amor;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
*{margin:0px;
padding:0px}


#myVideo{
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%}

#content-text{
position: absolute;
z-index:9999;
font-size:50px;
color:white;
margin:0px 150px;
margin-top:400px;
text-shadow:2px 0px 10px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1)
}

#content-text2{
    position: absolute;;
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
    margin:0px 100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-shadow:2px 0px 10px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1)
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pieza horóscopo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="content-text2">&nbsp;</div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Si con ese código te funciona qué problema hay?¿A qué te refieres con "cómo lo puedo acomodar?"?

Comment: No se si me funciona, me equivoque arriba, como lo podría acomodar en el código?  var content = document.getElementById('content-text');
    var content2 = document.getElementById('content-text2');

Comment: ¿Lo has probado? Porque, o te funciona o no te funciona. Si no te funciona trata de explicar con más detalle el problema, exactamente dónde no funciona. Si no funciona nada del código pues debes intentar otra forma. Pero para poder ayudarte debes decir exáctamente qué quieres que haga.

Comment: Exáctamente lo que quiero que haga es que se desaparezca el de abajo cuando aparezca el de arriba si me hago entender? el código en estos momentos funciona pero aparecen los dos arriba y abajo y no se desaparece uno entiendes ?

Comment: Santiago, debes poner el código todo lo claro que puedas. Poner tu HTML, tu CSS y tu Javascript. A continuación, explicar bien lo que quieres hacer, lo que has intentado y dónde da el error o te has quedado atascado. Y ya de paso hacer un [mcve] que nos facilite la vida. Si no es muy difícil ayudarte. No somos adivinos (de momento).